# Page transitions effects in Safari?

Tags: safari

How can I add Page transitions effects like IE in Safari for web pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check out this example: http://sachiniscool.blogspot.com/2006/01/implementing-page-transitions-in.html. It describes how to emulate page transitions in Firefox using AJAX and CSS. The same method works for Safari as well. The code below is taken from that page and slightly formatted:

```
var xmlhttp;
var timerId = 0;
var op = 1;

function getPageFx() {
  url = "/transpage2.html";
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=xmlhttpChange
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true)
    xmlhttp.send(null)
  } else getPageIE();
}

function xmlhttpChange() {
// if xmlhttp shows "loaded"
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
  // if "OK"
    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      if (timerId != 0)
        window.clearTimeout(timerId);
        timerId = window.setTimeout("trans();",100);
    } else {
       alert(xmlhttp.status)
    }
  }
}

function trans() {
  op -= .1;
  document.body.style.opacity = op;
  if(op < .4) {
    window.clearTimeout(timerId);
    timerId = 0; document.body.style.opacity = 1;
    document.open();
    document.write(xmlhttp.responseText);
    document.close();
    return;
  }
  timerId = window.setTimeout("trans();",100);
}

function getPageIE() {
  window.location.href = "transpage2.html";
}
```

Comment: Behaviour in all browsers Firefox 5 is that it doesn't change the page URL where IE transitions do. In Chrome 12 and Safari 5.1 the browser back skips the first page and goes to the referrer of that page. This does work in FireFox though. This test was performed via the original URL quoted in this answer and not the code pasted in above.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Scriptaculous](http://github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/wikis). Avoid IE-Only JS if that's what you are referring to (no idea what kind of effect you mean).