# How do you make an html page fade out while another fades in?

Tags: html, css

I have a client with an event planning site asking his pages to fade into one another. I have no idea how I can accomplish this. Any ideas? Is there anyway to do this without flash?

Comment: Fade transition pages always seems like a "web UI smell" to me.

Comment: I don't agree in principle it's a wrong idea, but how will this work in practice when a page-load takes several seconds? Normally a page loads incrementally as each image/part is received, will you have to wait for the entire page, including flash elements to load before starting the fade?

Comment: @John - Ajax can solve this problem.  Display a little loading gif while the page loads -> fade in/out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Definitely get hold of a javascript framework. jQuery is popular (because it's ace), but there's Mootools, Prototype, and Dojo to name a few.

I'm not sure if crosssfading can be done reliably across all the browsers without popping / jumping artifacts. Even the example Dancrumb points to is a bit ropey (no insult intended Dan).

Process-wise, you could have 3 layers (top to bottom)

- screen (initially invisible)
- page (one)
- container (initially empty)

when the user tries to navigate to the second page, load it into the container using ajax. Once the page has loaded, start fading up the screen. Once the screen is at 100% opacity, manipulate the DOM to move the loaded content out of the hidden container and into what is now page two, then start fading the screen back out again.

**EDIT** on a sidenote - I would summon up all my webdev mojo and try to convince the client what I bad idea it is to have complete page fades on an site designed to communicate information. Obviously I know sweet FA about this project so feel free to slap me down; but I've never seen a case where fancy effects and transitions has improved the usability of a site when used at the page level. I know it'd irritate me if I had to wait for a fancy transition to finish before I could continue navigating...

Comment: If it's a quick effect, like 0.5s, then I disagree... Windows has nice animate menus and minimize.maximize functionality as does MacOS (In fact more-so).

Comment: Opening menus and min / max -imising a screen are totally different interactions to navigating a page though...,

Comment: Improving usability can include cosmetic-only effects. I'd argue that while long transitions, or transitions on every page of the site, might get annoying, a single transition from, say, the home page to a deeper area can add a sense of polish. It just depends on the design. The user is probably not going to be inconvenienced by a .5s transition, given that they wouldn't have time to even scan the new page in that timeframe, much less be waiting for the transition to finish in order to click something.

Answer (score 6):

Page Transitions are supported natively with IE, using the `META` tag.
See the [Microsoft page about Filters and Transitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847%28VS.85%29.aspx#Interpage_Transition) for more

For a browser agnostic approach (using Javascript), see [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101877/page-transitions-effects-in-safari)

Comment: Note: Filters and Transitions are deprecated as of IE9.

Answer (score 5):

This should work, without relying on Ajax (jQuery) :

```
$(function(){

    /*
    Add this code to every page.

    We start by hiding the body, and then fading it in.
    */
    $('body').hide().fadeIn('fast');

    /*
    Now we deal with all 'a' tags...
    */
    $('a').click(function(){
        /*
        Get the url from this anchors href
        */
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        /*
        Fade out the whole page
        */
        $('body').fadeOut('fast', function(){
            /*
            When that's done (on the 'callback') send the browser to the link.
            */
            window.location.href = link;
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

Worth noting however is that if you're loading js at the bottom of the page (as we're often told to do), on a slow page load the page might be visible, then invisible, and then fade in again... Which would look very strange.

A solution would be to just hide the body in CSS, but you might, possibly, have visitors with JS turned off but CSS turned on, then they'll just have a blank page. Alternatively you could use a tiny amount of js at the top of the page (not relying on jQuery) to hide the body.

Lastly, however, why? I think if I visited your site these effects would begin to seriously annoy me pretty quickly. Why not just take the user to the page they asked for?

Answer (score 3):

Won't work in IE, but WebKit and FireFox are both on the boat with CSS transitions, and they run a lot more smoothly than any JavaScript.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/

Comment: IE has had powerpoint-esque page transitions since IE4. I dunno if they've pulled them by now though...

Comment: ...also, CSS transitions are transitions between two CSS values, not two distinct pages.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a little late, but to Fade a page In when it loads, and then fade out On-click I'd suggest using jQuery. I wrote this quick little script that will do the trick that your after. Have a look at it, and I will explain below.

The CSS

```
 body { display:none; }
```

The JS

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
        $( 'body' ).fadeIn("slow", 0.0);
        $( 'body' ).fadeIn("slow", 0.1);
        $( 'body' ).fadeIn("slow", 0.2);
        $( 'body' ).fadeIn("slow", 0.3);
        $( 'body' ).fadeIn("slow", 0.4);
        $( 'body' ).fadeIn("slow", 0.5);
        $( 'body' ).fadeIn("slow", 0.6);
        $( 'body' ).fadeIn("slow", 0.7);
        $( 'body' ).fadeIn("slow", 0.8);
        $( 'body' ).fadeIn("slow", 0.9);
        $( 'body' ).fadeIn("slow", 1.0);
                $('a').click(function(){
                $('body').fadeOut();
                 setTimeout("nav('"+this.href+"')",1000);
               return false;
       });
    });
function nav(href){
location.href=href;
};
```

The CSS holds back the display of the body, which allows the JS to start the fade effect on-load of the page. The body fadeIn is set at intervals to allow a smoother fadeIn effect, giving the site time to load. I've set the fadeOut effect to trigger when any anchor link is clicked (you could change it whatever you wish to act as the fade out trigger). When the page fades out, it will most likly fade to a 'White' screen. To avoid this, set your HTML background color to any HEX to match the sites color.

That script right there is probably the best solution and quickest to impliment on any site. It's been tested on IE7-8, FF 3+ and Opera 9-10 and works like a charm. Enjoy!

Comment: you might want to add a `noscript` section where you set un-hide the body, if a user has JS disabled.

Comment: Or just apply your CSS display none via jQuery first `$('body').css('display', 'none');`

Answer (score 1):

You could load the content using an AJAX request and then use javascript to fade out one page and fade in the other? In jQuery, something along the lines of:

```
$.get('newpage.html', {}, function(res){
    $('#content-container').fadeOut().html(res).fadeIn();
});
```

Not perfect, but it's a move in the right direction hopefully? This isn't really something HTML was made for...

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 1):

try this jQuery plugin. it's a [tutorial on page transitions](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/02/23/how-to-use-jquery-to-make-slick-page-transitions/)

Answer (score 0):

What happens with pages that contain Flash/Video elements or other complex stuff? Will those fade properly?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hacky way I just thought of. Similar to Alex Lawford's answer, but hopefully a bit better:

On clicking a link, send an AJAX request for the new page, but *don't do anything with the response*. Once you receive the response, then fade out the current page, issue a standard `window.location = <newurl>` command and have javascript on that side immediately hide and then fade in the new document.

The hope here is that the response from the AJAX call is cached, so the time between fade out and fade in will be negligible.

I'll just reiterate from the first sentence though: this is **hacky**.