# How do I add fade effect between content on two pages using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, transition, fade, slide

I have designed a simple website with a home and about page and a sliding contact form.  You can see the site [here](http://nickputman.com/test/index.html).

I would like to add a nice transition between the index and about pages.  I imagine the simplest solution would be a fade, but sliding content may look good too.  I have tried to implement the [dynamic page script on CSS tricks](http://css-tricks.com/6336-dynamic-page-replacing-content/), but couldn't get it working with the navigation system I have in place, and also the effects are not in the right order.  I presume the order would need to be:

1. Fade (or slide) out current page
2. Alter height of page to fit new content
3. Fade (or slide) in new page

I wonder if someone could recommend a suitable method for achieving the effect I am looking for.

Thanks,

Nick

**ADDED**

CLOSE BUTTON CLICK FUNCTION:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".close").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideUp("slow");
        $("#home").addClass("current");
        $("#contact").removeClass("current");
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

DELEGATE CLICK FUNCTION:

```
$("nav").delegate("a.fade", "click", function ()
    {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#panel").slideUp("slow");
        $(this).addClass("current");
        $("#contact").removeClass("current");
        return false;
    });
```

**FULL DYNAMICPAGE.JS**

```
$(function ()
{

    var newHash = "",
        $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
        $pageWrap = $("#page-wrap"),
        baseHeight = 0,
        $el,
        $panel = $("#panel");

    $panel.visible = false;


    $(window).bind('hashchange', function ()
    {

        newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

        if (newHash)
        {
            if ($panel.visible)
            {
                $pageWrap.animate({ height: "-=" + $panel.height() + "px" }, function ()
                {
                    $pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
                    $panel.visible = false;
                });
                $panel.slideUp();
                baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height() - $panel.height();
            }
            else
            {
                $pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
                baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();
            }

            $mainContent
                .find("#guts")
                .fadeOut(500, function ()
                {
                    $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts", function ()
                    {
                        $pageWrap.animate({ height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px" }, function ()
                        {
                            $mainContent.fadeIn(500);
                            $pageWrap.css("height", "auto");
                        });

                });
                });
        };
    });

    $("nav").delegate("a.fade", "click", function ()
    {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#panel").slideUp("slow");
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
        $("a").not(this).removeClass('clicked');
        $(".current", this).stop().animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, {
            duration: 100,
            specialEasing: {
                opacity: 'linear',
            },

        });

        $(".current").not($(".current",this)).stop().animate({
                    opacity: 0
                }, {
                    duration: 2000,
                    specialEasing: {
                        opacity: 'linear',
                    },

                });

        return false;
    });

    $("#nav-bottom").delegate("a", "click", function ()
    {
        $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
        return false;
    });


    $("#contact").click(function ()
    {
        $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
//        $(this).addClass("current");
//        $("#home, #about").removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
        $("a").not(this).removeClass('clicked');
        $(".current", this).stop().animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, {
            duration: 100,
            specialEasing: {
                opacity: 'linear',
            },

        });

        $(".current").not($(".current",this)).stop().animate({
                    opacity: 0
                }, {
                    duration: 2000,
                    specialEasing: {
                        opacity: 'linear',
                    },

                });

        $panel.visible = true;
        return false;
    });

    $(".close").click(function ()
    {
        $("#panel").slideUp("slow");
        $panel.visible = false;


        $(".current","#nav3").stop().animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, {
            duration: 2000,
            specialEasing: {
                opacity: 'linear',
            },

        });   

        return false;
    });

    $("nav a").hover(
        function() {
            if(!$(this).hasClass('clicked')){

            $(".current", this).stop().animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, {
                duration: 300,
                specialEasing: {
                    opacity: 'linear',
                },

            });
            }
        }, function() {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('clicked')){
            $(".current", this).stop().animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, {
                duration: 2000,
                specialEasing: {
                    opacity: 'linear',
                },

        });

        }
    });

    $(window).trigger('hashchange');

});
```

**HTML**

> ```
>  <div class="nav-image"><img src="images/bodhi-leaf-brown.png"></div>
>
>  <div class="current"><img src="images/bodhi-leaf-green.png"></div>
>  <div class="text"><img src="images/home.png"></div>
>
>  </a> </div>
> ```
>
> ```
>  <div class="nav-image"><img src="images/bodhi-leaf-brown.png" class="flip"></div>
>
>  <div class="current"><img src="images/bodhi-leaf-green.png" class="flip"></div>
>  <div class="text"><img src="images/about.png"></div>
>
>  </a> </div>
> ```
>
> ```
>  <a href="index.html" class="" id="contact">
>
>  <div class="nav-image"><img src="images/bodhi-leaf-brown.png"></div>
>
>  <div class="current"><img src="images/bodhi-leaf-green.png"></div>
>  <div class="text"><img src="images/contact.png"></div>
>
>  </a> </div>
> ```

**CSS**

```
nav {
    width: 650px;
    height: 170px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100;
    left: 200;
}

#nav1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 120px;
}

#nav2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 340px;
}

#nav3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 560px;
}


.nav-image  {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;

}

.current {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about why the one on CSS Tricks didn't work? I've taken a peek at it and your site and it looks like it should do what you want. (Except maybe for the delegate, which I'd be tempted to rewrite to include other links on the page.)

Comment: Hi. I got the CSS Tricks script working in part. The two main issues were as described above, i.e. I already have click functions on each page for opening and closing the contact form and changing the classes on the links. So I wasn't sure how to integrate this with the click function in the CSS Tricks script. Then, because the height of my index and about page are different, content was being faded in before the page was resized to the correct size for the new content, hence my wondering about changing the order of the effects.

Comment: Ah, my apologies - I didn't notice the order was wrong when I tried it out, but you're right. I've posted something below using the CSS Tricks code that hopefully works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do want to stick with the CSS Tricks code, I think it's possible to tweak it to work for you.

**Animation order**

I hadn't noticed when I tried it at first, but - you're right - the fade out, fade in new content, then adjust height animation order is rather silly. You can get it to do what you want by reversing the animation order

```
$pageWrap.animate({ height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px" }, function () { $mainContent.fadeIn(200); });
```

**Contact form**

You could exclude the contact form from triggering a hashchange by being more specific about what to include in the delegate, for instance (for link id `#contact`)

```
$("nav").delegate("a:not(#contact)", "click", function () { ... }
```

This may or may not do what you want, e.g. you may actually want the contact form to add a hash so people can link to it. In that case, you could add an `if` in the hashchange event to check for `#contact` (or whatever).

**Edit**

Following comments below, this dynamicpage.js code sets `$pageWrap` height to auto after the animation (so the contact thing works) and also recalculates the heights when used to allow page changes when the contact form is visible.

**Edit 2**

To handle scrolling up smoothly when the contact form is visible and fading links. The contact form did not scroll smoothly because you stored its original (expanded) height in `hashChange` and adjusted relative to that. Once the animation had finished and the fixed height had been removed through CSS, it jumped up to the much smaller current height. I've added a bit of code that adjusts the height if the contact form needs to be hidden.

The links fade because they're in the `#guts` div (and indeed inside the `#main-content` section, which does the actual fading. If you move them outside of that, things get better. Unfortunately they do then start to jump in the gap between the old `#guts` content being removed and the new stuff being added, so you could use a bit of CSS like below to get round this.

I don't think this is a great solution, though. If I were you, I'd hide the content, animate `#guts` to the new height and then add the content, so `#guts` never loses its CSS set height. Using `animate` would also allow you to queue the animations, which can be a problem occasionally at the moment if you click things too quickly.

```
$(function ()
{

    var newHash = "",
        $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
        $pageWrap = $("#page-wrap"),
        baseHeight = 0,
        $el,
        $panel = $("#panel");

    $panel.visible = false;

    $("nav").delegate("a", "click", function ()
    {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        return false;
    });

    $(window).bind('hashchange', function ()
    {

        newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

        if (newHash)
        {
            if ($panel.visible)
            {
                $pageWrap.animate({ height: "-=" + $panel.height() + "px" }, function ()
                {
                    $pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
                    $panel.visible = false;
                });
                $panel.slideUp();
                baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height() - $panel.height();
            }
            else
            {
                $pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
                baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();
            }

            $mainContent
                .find("#guts")
                .fadeOut(500, function ()
                {
                    $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts", function ()
                    {
                        $pageWrap.animate({ height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px" }, function ()
                        {
                            $mainContent.fadeIn(500);
                            $pageWrap.css("height", "auto");
                        });

                        $("nav a").removeClass("current");
                        $("nav a[href=\"" + newHash + "\"]").addClass("current");
                    });
                });
        };
    });

    $("#contact").click(function ()
    {
        $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
        $(this).addClass("current");
        $("#home, #about").removeClass("current");
        $panel.visible = true;
        return false;
    });

    $(".close").click(function ()
    {
        $("#panel").slideUp("slow");
        $(curTab).addClass("current");
        $("#contact").removeClass("current");
        $panel.visible = false;
        return false;
    });

    $(window).trigger('hashchange');

});
```

CSS

```
#nav-bottom {
    margin: -15px 0 15px -100px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Definitely a step in the right direction. If you look at the [current site](http://nickputman.com/test/) there are still at least a couple of issues: (1) When opening the contact form, the height of the page is not changing to accommodate the extra height of the contact form. Is this because of the height being set by the CSS Tricks script?  (2) I am not sure how to handle the links at the bottom of the page.  I have now included them in the #main-content (and #guts) div, so that they are faded in and out, but no space is allowed for them on the page.  I hope this is clear!

Comment: I think I have the navigation at the bottom sorted now, though would rather it didn't have to fade out with the content, but rather stuck to the bottom of the page during the transition.  I have noticed another issue though.  I added the code from the click functions for each of the nav links to the delegate in the CSS tricks script, and this works except for `$(this).addClass("current");`.  Presumably the script doesn't know what 'this' refers to.  How would I rewrite this so that the class "current" is added to a page when it is clicked on in the nav bar?  Thanks, Nick

Comment: @Nick You're right about the contact form height thing; I've added some code that sets the height to auto after animating so it doesn't interfere with the contact form. In the code I have (from your site), the class is added to `$("nav a[href=" + newHash + "]")`, not `$(this)`. Or am I looking in the wrong place? There is a mistake there, though (missing quotes), which I've also added above.

Comment: Thanks.  that's looking much better.  What I didn't realise is that using this hash method, the full about.html page isn't loaded, so the scripts in the head of the page on the about.html page are actually the scripts for the index.html.  I have a click function on the 'close this window' link in the contact form, which adds the class "current" to the nav link of the current page.  I have included this script at the end of my original question so that you can see it easily.  Is there a way of referring to the current page in this script, or better still including it in the CSS Tricks script?

Comment: It does actually load the whole page, but jQuery throws away everything not in `#guts` (as you don't need it again of course). If I were you, I'd store the current tab in a global during the Ajax call so you can use it when hiding the contact form. I've added a bit of code to the hashChange function to store the tab (this assumes the tab id will be the filename without `.html` (or something) on the end) and then just changed the close function to use it.

Comment: Thanks again. That helps a lot. I've marked the question as answered.  There are a couple of outstanding issues though, if you have the time, one directly related to the script and one not. (1)  I have added a few lines to the delegate click function (I have added this section of the script at the end of my original question). This is to handle the closing of the contact form when either the index or about nav links are clicked. The scrolling on the page when the user clicks the page other than the one they were on when they opened the contact form is not smooth - it just jumps up.

Comment: The other issue is finding a way to not fade out the links at the bottom of the page, in such a way that they stick to the bottom of the page (#page-wrap). I have tried a few things, including absolute positioning on the page-wrap div and relative positioning on the nav-bottom div, but the links still jump to the top of the main-content section.  Can you think of a way of achieving this?  Thanks, Nick

Comment: @Nick - Sorry for the delay. Added some more code & (hopefully useful) explanation re. those two issues.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the delay. The transitions are certainly looking better, though I agree could be improved a little. The most pressing issue is that I have changed the structure of the nav to divs with absolute positioning including hidden divs with green leaves which I am now fading in and out. The issue I'm having is how to fade the nav link for the index.html page to green when the page first loads, and how to fade the current tab to green with the close click function.  I'm happy to ask another question if you prefer. I've added current code at end of original question.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is not really intended to transition *between* pages but I guess you could hack something together whereby when someone clicks on the link you go `$('body').fadeout(slow);`
the only problem then is that the page could well load before the effect has time to complete, of course you can cancel default behavior, do the effect and then go to the desired page..

Comment: That would also be my guess. Catch the click event do a fadeout then jump the page. On the next page do a fadein.

Comment: The CSS Tricks example uses Ajax, but I've just had a look and whole page fades [have been](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596862/how-do-you-make-an-html-page-fade-out-while-another-fades-in) [discussed before](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/02/23/how-to-use-jquery-to-make-slick-page-transitions/). Rather irritating effect though...

Comment: yeah it's not something I've seen often but it's definitely doable

Comment: would sliding content be less irritating?

Comment: @Nick My main beef with this sort of thing is basically that expressed on the linked page (and indeed apparent in the demo on the linked site): they can slow things down unnecessarily and just get in the way - rather like a bad Flash site. But if they add a flourish and don't interfere with my browsing (or even add to the experience by giving useful feedback) then I'm cool with them. :)

Answer (score 2):

check this source, its in portuguese, but u can try:

[jquery-transitions-como-fazer-transicoes-de-paginas](http://jquerybrasil.org/jquery-transitions-como-fazer-transicoes-de-paginas/)

**html**

```
<div id="container">
<h1>This is the index </h1>
Some text with <a class="transition" href="http://jsfiddle.net/ruanltbg/Ns97H/3/embedded/result/">link</a>.This link will do the effect
```

```
<div id="container">
<h1>Other page </h1>
Will appear with a <a class="transition" href="http://jsfiddle.net/ruanltbg/WvD7Q/1/embedded/result/">link</a> to the index.
```

**js:**

```
$("#container").fadeIn(2000);
$("a.transition").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    link = this.href;
    $("body").fadeOut(1000, function(){
        window.location = link;
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ruanltbg/WvD7Q/1/light/)

Comment: ric basically has it right here, you should test it and accept this as the right answer